# download pdf from server using retrofit

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit

i have a problem with download pdf file from server, i found function which converte byte array, i am using android 10 xiaomi mi 9.

```
    private fun InputStream.saveToFile(file: String) = use { input ->
        File(file).outputStream().use { output ->
            input.copyTo(output)
        }
    }
```

if i using this fun i have exeption

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.securityenginee, PID: 4154
    java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:549)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:950)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:539)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:950) 
     Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: 1606998235369.pdf: open failed: EROFS (Read-only file system)
        at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:496)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:235)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:186)
        at com.example.securityenginee.view.fragment.contragentAndAppInfo.ActsAndCountsFragment.saveToFile(ActsAndCountsFragment.kt:339)
```

my permissions

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
        tools:ignore="ScopedStorage" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

this i check permission

```
        val permissionStatus1 =
            ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(requireContext(), Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
        if (permissionStatus1 == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "PERMISSION_GRANTED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }else if (permissionStatus1 == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED){
            Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "PERMISSION_DENIED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
```

all permission WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE and READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE send PERMISSION_GRANTED.

now i change function save file and his doesnt work too

```
    fun writeBytesAsPdf(bytes: ByteArray) {
        val path = requireContext().getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)
        var file = File.createTempFile("my_file", ".pdf", path)
        val fos = FileOutputStream(file)
        fos.write(bytes)
        fos.flush()
        fos.close()
        Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "test", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
```

Comment: Issue is in your file its read-only so its neither created nor you have proper permission

Comment: i adding all permission this doesent work too

Comment: Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: its clearly show that file is not created. first create a raw file with this name and also check before download start file.exist()
if its return false then create file

Comment: Can you post which android os you are using? The way you ask for permission and the way you write to a storage has changed for latests android versions.

Comment: i am adding all information